# Is Gleam of Authority's bonus constant or one-time?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I am looking for some clarification on the card [Gleam of Authority](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gleam%20of%20Authority).  The wording on the card is

> Enchantment - Aura

> Enchant Creature

> Enchanted creature gets +1/+1 for each +1/+1 counter on other creatures you control.

There is also a tap ability to bolster and vigilance. My question is on the enchanted creature get +1/+1 for each +1/+1 counter on other creatures you control.  Is this text a one time application?

For example, if I have 3 +1/+1 counters, my enchanted creature gets +3/+3.  If I add another +1/+1 counter to the board later, will the enchanted creature now have +4/+4 or will it remain +3/+3?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to B&CG!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a constant thing, not one-time, so if a creature you control gets another +1/+1 counter after the enchantment comes into play, the enchanted creature will increase in power and toughness.

The ability is a static ability, which means that it is in effect as long as the enchantment is in play, and its effect on the creature depends on the current board state, not the board state when the Enchantment entered the battlefield.

The relevant rules are these:

> - [**604.1.**](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Static_ability) **Static abilities do something all the time rather than being activated or triggered**. They are written as statements, and they're simply true.
> - [**604.2.**](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Static_ability) Static abilities create continuous effects, some of which are prevention effects or replacement effects. **These effects are active as long as the permanent with the ability remains on the battlefield and has the ability**, or as long as the object with the ability remains in the appropriate zone, as described in rule 112.6.
> - [**611.3a**](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Continuous_effects) A continuous effect generated by a static ability isn’t "locked in"; it applies at any given moment to whatever its text indicates.